Show that even and $2\pi$-periodic continutation is differentiable
Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by an even and $2\pi$-periodic continuation of
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}4x^2-\pi^2,&x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\8\pi x-3\pi^2-4x^2,&x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right].\end{cases}
$$
Show that $f$ is continously differentiable.

My approach:
As $f(-x)=f(x)$ the even and $2\pi$-periodic continuation of $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ attains the form of
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}-8\pi x-3\pi^2-4x^2,&x\in\left[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\4x^2-\pi^2,&x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\8\pi x-3\pi^2-4x^2,&x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right].\end{cases}
$$
We define $I_1:=\left[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ , $I_2:=\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $I_3:=\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]$ then each restriction $f_{|I_1}$, $f_{|I_2}$, $f_{|I_3}$is obviously continously differentiable.
We see that $f'_{|I_1}(x)=-8\pi-8x$, $f'_{|I_2}(x)=8x$ and $f'_{|I_3}(x)=8\pi-8x$. Since, \begin{align*}
&f'_{|I_1}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-4\pi=f'_{|I_2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&f'_{|I_2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=4\pi=f'_{|I_3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&f'_{|I_3}\left(\pi\right)=0=f'_{|I_1}\left(-\pi\right)\\
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
&f'(x):=\begin{cases}-8\pi-8x,&x\in\left[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\8x,&x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\8\pi-8x,&x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right].\end{cases}
\end{align*}
S0 $f$ is continously differentiable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and due to $2\pi$-periodicity on $\mathbb{R}$.

I am not sure if my continuation of $f$ is correct and if I can show the differentiability of $f$  this way?

@BrevanEllefsen, what do you exactly mean by continuity at the endpoints? As $f'(\pi)=f'(-\pi)$ it is clear that $f'$ is continuous, isn't it?

Yes, you are correct. I was more referring to your statements that your functions are differentiable on closed intervals, which is a mildly dangerous thing to say (it's true here, but is usually defined to mean they are differentiable on an open neighborhood of the closed set). What you've written is correct and your proof is done.

@BrevanEllefsen, if I look at the differentialquotient I get $\lim\limits_{x\nearrow -\pi}\frac{f(x)-f(-\pi)}{x+\pi}=\lim\limits_{x\nearrow -\pi}\frac{8\pi x-4\pi^2-4x^2}{x+\pi}=\lim\limits_{x\nearrow -\pi}(-4)\frac{(x-\pi)^2}{x+\pi}\neq0 $. This contradicts my solution?!
